# How does one modify the title bar at top of gnome desktop?

Tags: gnome-shell

Using Debian Wheezy (with gnome-3):
My panel (tray, taskbar, launcher bar) at the top of the screen has become crowded with shortcuts, etc., and I can't figure out how to remove them.

How do I remove shortcuts and other entries for the panel an top of screen in gnome-3?

Comment: @Mike Try to press `alt` + right click on launcher icon.

Comment: I switched to `kde` as I could not get gnome to do what I wanted.

Comment: I have rewritten question, using images from this site to get context http://wp.xin.at/archives/932.

Comment: Install `gnome-tweak-tool` and examine the extensions you have. The default panel has very few options for customization and definitely does not include a list of shortcuts.

Answer (score 4):

As @muru stated above your best bet is to install "gnome-tweak-tool" which comes with a lot of options for "tweaking" tweaking your gnome desktop. Once that is installed you can then visit [Gnome Shell Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/) and install extensions to add even more tweaking power to gnome.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling with extension icon crowding, I recommend installing this extension, which lets you hide icons temporarily without disabling the extensions in GNOME. https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/351/icon-hider/